# IE8 hangs while printing using windows.print() works fine in mozila

Tags: sharepoint

We are using a javascript "windows.print()" in a hyperlink from share Point form. This is working sometime first two or three times and then it hangs, then we have to kill the IE. If we right click on the form give print it will work

The same is working fine in Mozila. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Please could you advise

Thanks,
Sijo JO

Comment: I have changed to the below code and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed to the below java code and it worked

```
 function openDialog()
  {
   // Prompt user where to save, or use a input type of file 
   document.execCommand("Print",true,null);
  }


input type="button" id="htmlBtn" value="Save as an HTML document" onClick="openDialog()"
```